# How to fill the prompt in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I use a command like this:

```
get-pfxcertificate C:\test.pfx

Enter password: *******
```

The command ask me to fill the prompt. But I can't do that in my script (test.ps1 for ex)

What I need is like this:

```
get-pfxcertificate C:\test.pfx -password "123456"
```

or something similar so I can run my script without fill in the prompt each time

I'm very thankful for any reply

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no Password parameter, you can try with a .NET class:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import('C:\test.pfx','123456','DefaultKeySet')
```

Comment: [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait( "123456~" )

Comment: That would also solve the problem, but not good enough for me, since if get-pfxcertificate does not ask for the prompt, the above command will expose my password. Your solution is really good. Thanks very much

Comment: @ngubk, you can use `Read-Host` to prompt for the password. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30602978/124069

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to extend the abilities of `Get-PfxCertificate`, essentially enabling the password to be passed in.

```posh
# create a backup of the original cmdlet
if(Test-Path Function:\Get-PfxCertificate){
    Copy Function:\Get-PfxCertificate Function:\Get-PfxCertificateOriginal
}

# create a new cmdlet with the same name (overwrites the original)
function Get-PfxCertificate {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='ByPath')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='ByPath')] [string[]] $filePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='ByLiteralPath')] [string[]] $literalPath,

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='ByPath')] 
        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='ByLiteralPath')] [string] $password,

        [Parameter(Position=2, ParameterSetName='ByPath')]
        [Parameter(Position=2, ParameterSetName='ByLiteralPath')] [string] 
        [ValidateSet('DefaultKeySet','Exportable','MachineKeySet','PersistKeySet','UserKeySet','UserProtected')] $x509KeyStorageFlag = 'DefaultKeySet'
    )

    if($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByPath'){
        $literalPath = Resolve-Path $filePath 
    }

    if(!$password){
        # if the password parameter isn't present, just use the original cmdlet
        $cert = Get-PfxCertificateOriginal -literalPath $literalPath
    } else {
        # otherwise use the .NET implementation
        $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
        $cert.Import($literalPath, $password, $X509KeyStorageFlag)
    }

    return $cert
}
```

And now you can call it

```posh
# tada: extended cmdlet with `password` parameter
Get-PfxCertificate 'C:\path\to\cert.pfx' 'password'
```

Also, if you still need the prompt, you can do something like this.

```posh
$pwd = Read-Host 'Please enter your SSL Certificate password.'
Get-PfxCertificate 'C:\path\to\cert.pfx' $pwd
```

Answer (score 6):

There is now a `Get-PfxData` command in PowerShell that gets the certificate and chain. The command includes a `-Password` parameter that takes a SecureString object so you can avoid being prompted.

The `EndEntityCertificates` property contains an array of certificates at the end of the certificate chain and will contain the same certificate object created by the `Get-PfxCertificate` command.

The following example converts a normal string to a SecureString object, loads the certificates from a file, then assigns the first/only end certificate to the $SigningCert variable:

```
$SecurePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$PfxData=Get-PfxData -FilePath ".\cert_filename.pfx" -Password $SecurePassword
$SigningCert=$PfxData.EndEntityCertificates[0]
```

You can now apply $SigningCert without being prompted for the password.

Comment: Shew, I was just struggling with this.  Thanks!  And I guess to make my comment not totally useless, here's a 1 line version.
(Get-PfxData -FilePath "C:\yada\yada.pfx" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyPassword") -Force -AsPlainText ).EndEntityCertificates[0]

Answer (score 3):

If you are forced to use Windows Powershell (v5.*), then previous solutions in the thread are for you.

However if you can use Powershell 7/Powershell Core, then its own `Get-PfxCertificate` command **does** have a `-Password` parameter.

After installing Powershell 7 and making sure to use `pwsh` and not `powershell`, you can load the certificate that way:

```
$certificate = (Get-PfxCertificate <certificate_path>.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Shay for pointing me in the right direction.
My need was getting the Thumbprint from the PFX file, so I used the non-persistent DefaultKeySet.
Testing under 2012 PS3 fails unless the key set is fully qualified.
Also, a blank space between Import and left parenthesis, i.e. "$cert.Import^^(Sys..." causes an error.  Picky, picky parser.

My PFX password is encrypted in the source.
I decrypt it at runtime so it is not visible in the souce.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
[string] $strPW  = '123456'
[string] $strPFX = 'C:\MyCert.pfx'

$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($strPFX,$strPW,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"DefaultKeySet")
$cert.Thumbprint
```

Answer (score -2):

This also works using native PowerShell instead of .NET:

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $strPW -Force -AsPlainText
$cert = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $strPFX cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $securePassword
```

Comment: the OP isn't using `Import`, they're using `get` which doesn't have the password parameter by default.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is confusing. PowerShell 3.0's native Get-PfxCertificate Cmdlet provides a lot of functionality on the .pfx file, but doesn't allow a password to be passed in as SecureString. This answer is about the PKI module's Import-PfxCertificate CmdLet, which does accept a password parameter, but lacks functionality in comparison.